# Images with transparent backgrounds show white background

Tags: flutter, dart

So I've been struggling with this for a while, but the problem is that whenever I add an image in my ui It shows a white background, even though It's supposed to be transparent, I have checked my pubspec.yaml file and the images are well imported but I just don't know why it shows the transparent background as white

```
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      child: Image.asset("assets/send.png"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      height: 40,
                      width: 40,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.lightBlue])),
                    ),
                  )
```

This is the code that I'm writing and the image shows itself like this:
[The image that has a transparent background has a white background now for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx4hP.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much for reading.

[The image in question without the Gesture detector and bigger so the transparent parts are more visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl7sc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate that error,

but on my device it just shows the image with the decoration.

Maybe try first using it in Flutter without decoration or GestureDetector. If that works, try again.

Also, I don't see where your image should be transparent. If that link is correct, I just see a 359x58 image that does not have any transparent parts.

As an exercise, you could also try making this out of a Flutter Card widget. That's very much like the image and more customizable (you need the message icon though).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried what you said, though it still shows It's supposedly transparent parts, I exaggerated the size to make the transparent background more visible and will update the post with the image that I want to use